# Groovy: unable to resolve class when running from command line

Tags: shell, groovy, command-line

I'm trying to run a groovy script from command line. It runs fine in a gradle project in intellij, but when I try to run it via command line I get several errors like this one

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup 
failed:
/home/tpulayan/jenkins- 
watcher/src/main/groovy/attempt_authentification.groovy: 1: unable to resolve 
class in.ashwanthkumar.slack.webhook.Slack
@ line 1, column 1.
  import in.ashwanthkumar.slack.webhook.Slack
  ^

1 error
```

My code:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='in.ashwanthkumar', module='slack-java-webhook', 
version='0.0.7')
)

import in.ashwanthkumar.slack.webhook.Slack
import in.ashwanthkumar.slack.webhook.SlackMessage
import org.apache.http.HttpException
import org.apache.http.HttpHost
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScheme
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthState
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils


use(TimerMethods) {
    def timer = new Timer()
    def periodSeconds = 600

    new Slack()
            .icon(':exclamation:')
            .sendToChannel('jenkins-monitoring')
            .displayName('Jenkins Watcher')
            .push(new SlackMessage("Jenkins Watcher started at ${new Date()}. Started to monitor the status of deb-jenkins-prd..."))

    def task = timer.runEvery(1000, periodSeconds * 1000) {
        def response = getAuthentication().statusCode
        if (response != 200) {
            new Slack()
                    .icon(':exclamation:')
                    .sendToChannel('jenkins-monitoring')
                    .displayName('Jenkins Watcher')
                    .push(new SlackMessage("Login attempt by Jenkins Watcher failed at ${new Date()}. This could indicate that Jenkins is stuck! Request response code is: ${response}"))
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose it's something related to the classpath but I was unable to solve it.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT AFTER RESPONSE

I've updated my code with the @Grab but unfortunately I get this error when running it from command line:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: in.ashwanthkumar#slack-java-webhook;0.0.7: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: in.ashwanthkumar#slack-java-webhook;0.0.7: not found]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.getDependencies(GrapeIvy.groovy:464)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `build.gradle` seems you have defined dependencies.

you can put all dependencies (*.jar) into `./lib` dir and run your groovy script like this:

```
groovy -cp ./lib/* MyScript.groovy
```

or you can specify all the dependencies using [`Grape/Grab`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) directly in your groovy script then your command line will be simple and groovy will download all dependencies on script start

```
groovy MyScript.groovy
```

Comment: I've added @Grab but now I get an error on that, please see updated question

Comment: the `@Grab(group='in.ashwanthkumar', module='slack-java-webhook', version='0.0.7')` works fine for me. probably your script can't access internet to download dependency. you can try to run your script with resolving debug : `groovy -Divy.message.logger.level=4 MyScript.groovy`

Comment: Yes, the issue was due to my corporate proxy. Thanks!